# Access 2010 Day Combo Box

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to have 3 combo boxes for users to enter dates. The Month and Year combo boxes are very easy but I'm having trouble with the day combo box. I want this to be an intelligent box in that it will only display days based on the month, ie. 28 when month is set to February and 31 if on January.

I'm just wondering if there is an easy way I should look at to accomplish this, I tried some VBA that was unsuccessful.

What I have done is that I essentially used `addItem` for all days 1-28 and then had `IF` checks to see if i needed 29, 30 or 31 days. Errors occurred when I would go from a month with 31 days to 30 and then to 29/28 because it would attempt to remove 31 from the list but it wouldn't exist since when switching to the 30 day month got ride of 31. Unless there's a way to bypass this I need a pointer to the right direction.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you want to do this? You could instead use a 'date' input mask and even supply a datepicker

Comment: You might be able to create a table to drive the combo box.

Comment: The reason for this is because I need the date and time, so rather then have a dozen checks to see how people may enter info differently I have these combo boxes, so I am positive on how they enter data. It works great I just wanted to upgrade it another step by having the days be dependent on the month & year combo box.

Comment: Is there an appliance already built to handle this?.. Do Jet and SQL Server DATE datatypes detect invalid dates and handle date arithmetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say something like:

```
Me.cboDay.RowSource = "SELECT Number " _
& "FROM MyNumbersTable " _
& "WHERE Number < = " & Day(DateSerial(Me.cboYear,Me.cboMonth+1,0))
```

Where MyNumersTable is a table of integers

Note that

```
Day(DateSerial(2012,2+1,0)) = 29
```